# Are Monkey Banks less effective after round 80 in Bloons TD 6?

Tags: bloons-td-6

I cannot find any hard evidence for this, but Monkey Banks (a 2-3-0 Banana Farm) seem far less effective when entering free play (after round 80). I tend to collect my balance, sell the banks, and recreate the farms on either top path (banana drops) or bottom path (marketplace). Are Monkey Banks less effective when entering free play?

Comment: If you are serious about farming like for boss events, the current meta is many overclocked BRFs and merchantman with Trade empire if there's water.